# Changing Product/Category URL_KEY doesn't create a 301 redirect ( EE 1.13)

Tags: redirect, ee-1.13, url-rewrite

I'm on EE 1.13.10 and I noticed that changing `URL key` for a product/category doesn't create a redirect from the previous URL to the new one, instead both URL still works.

Any hint on out to debug/solve the issue ?

**UPDATE**
-- Example --
I changed URL key from `abc123` to `123abc` (prod. id:123) and ran a full re-index.

**After that:**

The link in the frontend are correct but `Url_Rewrite table` shows following data:

- abc123.html  -> catalog/product/view/id/123
- 123abc.html  -> catalog/product/view/id/123

**So:**

1. The redirect from `abc123` to `123abc` is missed here
2. Both URLs point to the controller (so both links works)

**As said above the correct behavior should be that the previous Url redirect to the new one and this is not happening**

Comment: If the problem persists after a reindex, can you show what is in core_url_rewrite for these products?

Comment: I have added more details

Comment: Do mind that 1.13 does not write rewrites to core_url_rewrite anymore. It utilizes the enterprise_url_rewrite table instead. Perhaps it's present in there?

Comment: it is related to the url_rewrite changes introduced in 1.13.x ... in this new version they change this behavior ( only god knows why )

Comment: Your last update sounds like the answer to your question. Can you please add that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: make sense, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Magento EE Support this the default and expected behavior on 1.13.x